# Azure Web App Trace logs not appearing in log

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am using Azure Web App Application Logging, and I followed the online tutorial, and made the following setup:

[image: Logging configuration settings]

I get an exception and in my `catch` block I have the following code:

```
Trace.TraceError("abc");
Trace.TraceInformation("abc");
Trace.TraceWarning("abc");
Trace.WriteLine("abc");
Console.WriteLine("abc");
```

In the logs I get this:

> 2017-02-13 03:30:14 ~1ENGINEMAILERAPI GET /api/vfs/site/wwwroot/
>   _=1486950157594&X-ARR-LOG-ID=149fee3f-8da3-460e-816e-10e7a4b95f1d 443 - 121.121.23.217 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36
>   - https://web1.appsvcux.ext.azure.com/websites/WebsitesContent/WebsitesIndex?cacheability=3&defaultCloudName=azure&extensionName=WebsitesExtension&shellVersion=5.0.302.608%20(production%233ec7ddd.170201-1022)&traceStr=&region=southeastasia&flight=0&defaultCacheEvictionDelay=105000&websitesextension_enablemonitoringgroup=true&websitesextension_newauditlogs=true&websitesextension_resourcemenu=true&websitesextension_seetemplate=true&pageVersion=5.12.32.464175.170208-1137&l=en.en-us&trustedAuthority=portal.azure.com
>   enginemailerapi.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 992 1923 62

How can I get my application logging to show up?

Comment: This error you got from FTP or Blob Storage? Also, please check the following doc page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio hi dear, i get it from the FTP , and i was totally follow it, may i know if i need to add any trace listener to it?

Comment: Have you solved this issue, any updates?

Comment: @Bruce-MSFTnope... i still unable to do it, it wasted too much of time... it probably i created web service myself, when i create a new project, i created as a empty website not azure website, probably this is the cause

Comment: Are you deploying to a particular deployment slot other than the default (production)? If so, make sure that you are enabling Diagnostic Logs and look in the Log Stream blades from the Deployment Slot blade itself. It happened to me. I enabled logging on the default when I was testing on my "staging" slot. Once I realized my mistake I went to App > Deployment Slots > staging > Diagnostic Logs and voila! logs started streaming right away.

Answer (score 1):

According to the log format of error message you provided, I assumed that the log file you provided is belongs to **Web Server Logs** ( under `/LogFiles/http/RawLogs`) which formatted using [W3W Logging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa814385.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Based on your configuration, you have both enabled file system and blob storage for Application Logging. You could retrieve your application logs as follows:

**Application Logging (Filesystem)**

For a simple way, you could leverage [KUDU](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/), click "Debug console > CMD" and `cd LogFiles\Application`, then you could retrieve your logs as follows:

[image]

**Application Logging (Blob)**

You could leverage [Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/) to retrieve your logs as follows:

[image]

**UPDATE：**

[image]

[image]

Comment: dear, it appear this in the file
2017-02-14T02:19:48  PID[11164] Verbose     SnapshotHelper::TakeSnapshotTimerCallback
2017-02-14T02:19:48  PID[11164] Verbose     SnapshotHelper::TakeSnapshotInternal - no new files in CodeGen

Comment: Are you mean that you couldn't retrieve your custom error message in the application log file? I used `System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError` and I could retrieve my logs. I assumed that there may be a delay for log to be generated, you could wait for a while and refresh your KUDU site or storage tool to see whether you could retrieve your desired error message.

Comment: still get the same as 
2017-02-14T02:19:48 PID[11164] Verbose SnapshotHelper::TakeSnapshotTimerCallback 2017-02-14T02:19:48 PID[11164] Verbose SnapshotHelper::TakeSnapshotInternal - no new files in CodeGen

Comment: this is the content of the file

Comment: I found a similar [issue](https://github.com/jakubgarfield/Bonobo-Git-Server/issues/556) mentioned about `SnapshotHelper`. Also, I have set my applicaiton log level to `verbose` which could log all information produced by the application, I could retrieve the same verbose message as you provided, please see my updates. I assumed that `SnapshotHelper` is an Azure thing. I noticed that the time stamp of your logs are the same, you could try to set log level to error and clean your log files, then you could manually throw an exception and try to see whether you could retrieve your custom message.